Nuxt 3 data gets lost when switching pages
I have a Nuxt 3 application with two pages:

Index /
Catalog /catalog

Catalog uses vue-instantsearch from Algolia in order to run a product catalog. Because I need to restrict the results to a specific subset of my Algolia index, I need to create a secured api key on server side which then gets passed to the client side.
This works fine as long as I visit the /catalog page first or when I reload the page "hard" via cmd+r. But when I visit / first and then navigate to the /catalog via <NuxtLink to="catalog">...</NuxtLink> the backend part does not execute. So I am missing the data and the catalog does not work.
I could add an external to the <NuxtLink> part which forces Nuxt to load the /catalog page as external page ("hard" reload). But I want to have the smooth navigation experience as user.
Is there a way to force the page doing the async call without hard loading the page?
Here is my code:
<template>
    <div v-if="searchConfigRef">
        <ProductsCatalog :index="searchConfigRef.value.algoliaIndex"
            :secured-api-key="searchConfigRef.value.securedApiKey"
            :algolia-project="searchConfigRef.value.algoliaProject" whitelabel="faaren_marketplace"
            class="catalog-page-wrapper" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite'
const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()

const {data: searchConfigRef, error, execute, refresh} = await useAsyncData(() => {
    const algoliaProject = runtimeConfig.algolia.project
    const algoliaIndex = runtimeConfig.algolia.index
    const algoliaManagementKey = runtimeConfig.algolia.managementKey

    const adminClient = algoliasearch(algoliaProject, algoliaManagementKey)

    const validUntil = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600 // 1 hour in the future
    const secKey = adminClient.generateSecuredApiKey(algoliaManagementKey, {
        validUntil
    })

    return { secKey, algoliaProject, algoliaIndex }
})
</script>

As you can see I need to create a secured api key on server side which then gets passed to the catalog-component on the frontend.

You can check if the key exists in the config, otherwise create an endpoint that will just return the management key as a JSON and plug that call into the rest of your function.
